# How to add empty area in a linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a image button on the right side of the row in my linearlayout. I tried it with padding left which works but a grey shadow is visible for the padding area. How can I achieve this with linearlayout but without the shadow. Does someone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:gravity="right"` into your XML code should do the trick. Essentially, this will force the View to head to the right part of the view.